# How to save Seekbar progress in shared Preferences in android?

Tags: android

```
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,sharedPreferences1 ;
private String Key_PROGRESS = "key_progress";
private String Key = "key_value";
private String PREFERENCE_PROGRESS = "preference_progress";
private String Key_PROGRESS1 = "key_progress1";
private String Key1 = "key_value1";
private String Seconds = "seconds";
private String PREFERENCE_PROGRESS1 = "preference_progress1";

oncreate methd()
{
   sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_PROGRESS , Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   currentProgress = sharedPreferences.getInt(Key_PROGRESS, 0);
}  


seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        newProgressValue = seekBar.getProgress();
        currentProgress = newProgressValue ;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt(Key_PROGRESS, newProgressValue);
        editor.commit();
```

Comment: Code is wrong. Please post it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the correct answer i am saving three seekbar values at a time,

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener {

```
public TextView progress1;

private SeekBar bar1;


private int savedProgress1;

private int loadedProgress1;

private String Key_PROGRESS_1 = "bar1_progress";


SharedPreferences mPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;



/*********************
 *
 * ONCREATE
 *
 ********************/


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.configuracion2);



    bar1 = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekbar); //make seekbar object
    bar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);   //set seekbar listener
    progress1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.summary);



    mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    editor = mPreferences.edit();



}


public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar bar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    Log.v("", "" + bar);
    switch (bar.getId()) {
        case R.id.fast_bar:
            progress1.setText(progress + "%");
            break;
        case R.id.climb_bar:
            progress2.setText(progress + "%");
            break;
        case R.id.platform_bar:
            progress3.setText(progress + "%");
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
}
@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    seekBar.setSecondaryProgress(seekBar.getProgress());
}




protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    loadedProgress1 = mPreferences.getInt("Key_PROGRESS_1", 0);
    bar1.setProgress(loadedProgress1);

    loadedProgress2 = mPreferences.getInt("Key_PROGRESS_2", 0);
    bar2.setProgress(loadedProgress2);

    loadedProgress2 = mPreferences.getInt("Key_PROGRESS_3", 0);
    bar3.setProgress(loadedProgress3);

}




protected void onPause(/*SeekBar seekBar*/) {
    super.onPause();

    savedProgress1 = bar1.getProgress();
    editor.putInt(Key_PROGRESS_1, savedProgress1);
    savedProgress2 = bar2.getProgress();
    editor.putInt(Key_PROGRESS_2, savedProgress2);
    savedProgress3 = bar3.getProgress();
    editor.putInt(Key_PROGRESS_3, savedProgress3);
    editor.commit();
}
```

}}

Comment: This was actually really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you're trying to achieve but I'm assuming this is some kind of settings activity so I'd suggest saving the value in the method onStop. Here's how you should do it:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private const String PREFS_NAME = "progress_prefs";
    private const String PROGRESS_KEY = "progress_key";
    private int progressValue = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                progressValue = progress;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        prefs.edit()
            .putInt(PROGRESS_KEY, progressValue)
            .apply()
    }
}
```

If that is not the solution you're looking for, please clarify your question.

Comment: Thanks buddy but my question is that, how do i save my seekbar progress in sharedprefrences?

Comment: Exactly the way I wrote it. prefs.edit().putInt(..).apply()

Comment: still facing the same prob

Comment: You didn't even explain what is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
      mySeek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

//                progress = progress / 45;
//                progress = progress * 45;
                Log.i(TAG, "OnSeekBarChangeListener():progress " + progress);
                mProgress = progress;
            }

 @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        SharedPreferenceHelper.setSharedPreferenceInt(configActivity.this, SharedPreferenceHelper.PREF_FORTUDE_WALPHABKGND, mProgress);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is only missing `seekBar.setProgress(currentProgress)` in your onCreate